# libicuuc.so.55: cannot open shared object file

Tags: swift, ubuntu

While am compile using swift build, am getting following error in my Ubuntu machine

```
$swift build

/home/xxxxxxxxx/Downloads/swift-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2016-02-25-a-ubuntu15.10/us
r/bin/swift-build: error while loading shared libraries: libicuuc.so.55: cannot
open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can i fix this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

You can manually download the good .dep

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu55_55.1-7_amd64.deb
```

Then you run:

```
sudo dpkg -i libicu55_55.1-7_amd64.deb
```

If it miss some dependency:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

It has worked for me.
Your can find the other architecture on the debian package website :

https://packages.debian.org/sid/libicu55

p.s: I know this is on SID, but this is the only version that I found

*note...packages may have been removed

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion that the OP may be working on an Raspberry Pi. If so, or for anyone finding this answer and being on a Pi this answer will help you except change `libicu55_55.1-7_amd64.deb` to `libicu55_55.1-7_armhf.deb`. You will also most likely have to `sudo apt-get install libcurl3`

Comment: The links for that package are broken. Is there any new correct links for download?

Comment: `wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu55_55.1-7_amd64.deb` this one works.

Answer (score 4):

Your system lacks a critical component for building Swift, `libicu-dev`.

Install this:

```
sudo apt-get install libicu-dev
```

---

But that was for *building Swift from source*. You were talking about building *with* Swift, my apologies.

Unfortunately it seems it won't work either: Swift for Linux only *officially* runs on **Ubuntu 15.10 and 14.04**, and you tell me in the comments that you're running 15.04.

I know there's tutorials on the web on how to make it work on Mint and other distros... But the best would be, if possible, that you update your install of course.

Comment: Ok. What gives `swift --version` on your machine?

Comment: `Swift version 3.0-dev (LLVM b361b0fc05, Clang 11493b0f62, Swift fc261045a5)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`

Comment: Well, that should be ok. You're on a 15.10 install, right?

Comment: Am using `No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 15.04
Release: 15.04
Codename: vivid`

Comment: That's why it fails. Different library versions. Swift officially only works for Ubuntu **15.10** and **14.04**. But I know there's tutorials on the web on how to make it work on Mint and other distros... But the best would be, if possible, that you update your install of course.

Comment: Ok eric i will upgrade and check it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I searched on the net and find a list in [debian packages](https://packages.debian.org/sid/i386/libicu55/filelist) that shows the `libicuuc.so.55` file.

```
apt-get install libicu55
```

Will resolve the issue.

Comment: The links for that package are broken. Is there any new correct links for download?

Answer (score 1):

hallow_me's link to download libicu55_55.1-7_amd64.deb doesn't work.
Here are the latest links https://packages.debian.org/stretch/amd64/libicu57/download

Like

```
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/i/icu/libicu55_55.1-7_amd64.deb
```

Then follow hallow_me's instruction to install it.

Comment: The link for that package are broken as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try the followings lines

```
echo "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main" | sudo tee --append /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libicu55
```