# Installing PhantomJS on shared hosting (1and1)

Tags: php, phantomjs, composer-php, shared-hosting, php-phantomjs

Using 1and1 linux shared hosting,

I have installed:

PHP Version 7.0.27
PHP PhantomJS 2.1.1

PHP PhantomJS all values are null

Whenever I make a request with:

```
$client = Client::getInstance();

$client->getEngine()->setPath($main_path.'core/composer/bin/phantomjs');
$client->getEngine()->addOption('--ssl-protocol=any');
$client->getEngine()->addOption('--ignore-ssl-errors=true');
$client->getEngine()->addOption('--web-security=false');
$client->getEngine()->addOption('--debug=true');
$client->getEngine()->addOption('--local-to-remote-url-access=true');

$request = $client->getMessageFactory()->createRequest("http://luclaverdure.com");
$response = $client->getMessageFactory()->createResponse();

$client->send($request, $response);
var_dump($request);
var_dump($response);

if($response->getStatus() === 200) {
    $resp = $response->getContent();
    var_dump($resp);
}
```

I have a bunch of null values and the URL doesn't get processed by phantomJS...

Request:

```
object(JonnyW\PhantomJs\Http\Request)#113 (12) {
    ["type":protected]=> NULL
    ["headers":protected]=> array(0) {}
    ["settings":protected]=>
      array(1) {
        ["resourceTimeout"]=>
        int(5000)
      }
    ["cookies":protected]=>
      array(2) {
        ["add"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["delete"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
    ["data":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    ["url":protected]=>
      string(59) "http://luclaverdure.com"
    ["method":protected]=>
      string(3) "GET"
    ["timeout":protected]=>
      NULL
    ["delay":protected]=>
      int(0)
    ["viewportWidth":protected]=>
      int(0)
    ["viewportHeight":protected]=>
      int(0)
    ["bodyStyles":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
}
```

Response:

```
object(JonnyW\PhantomJs\Http\Response)#263 (9) {
    ["headers"]=>
      NULL
    ["status"]=>
      NULL
    ["content"]=>
      NULL
    ["contentType"]=>
      NULL
    ["url"]=>
      NULL
    ["redirectURL"]=>
      NULL
    ["time"]=>
      NULL
    ["console"]=>
      NULL
    ["cookies"]=>
      NULL
}
```

It just never returns content

Please help

Edit: Logs:

> string(1413) "2018-02-25T22:31:25 [DEBUG] CookieJar - Created and will
>   store cookies in: "cookies.txt" 1   0x1b67967
>   /kunden/homepages/0/d220355082/htdocs/bitme/core/composer/bin/phantomjs()
>   [0x1b67967] 2   0x1baaaf5
>   /kunden/homepages/0/d220355082/htdocs/bitme/core/composer/bin/phantomjs()
>   [0x1baaaf5] 3   0x198c463
>   /kunden/homepages/0/d220355082/htdocs/bitme/core/composer/bin/phantomjs()
>   [0x198c463] 4   0x1ab3982
>   /kunden/homepages/0/d220355082/htdocs/bitme/core/composer/bin/phantomjs()
>   [0x1ab3982] 5   0x79abb9
>   /kunden/homepages/0/d220355082/htdocs/bitme/core/composer/bin/phantomjs()
>   [0x79abb9]        6   0x76b6f9
>   /kunden/homepages/0/d220355082/htdocs/bitme/core/composer/bin/phantomjs()
>   [0x76b6f9]        7   0x750a5d
>   /kunden/homepages/0/d220355082/htdocs/bitme/core/composer/bin/phantomjs()
>   [0x750a5d] 8   0x41cd89
>   /kunden/homepages/0/d220355082/htdocs/bitme/core/composer/bin/phantomjs()
>   [0x41cd89] 9   0x41f5c4
>   /kunden/homepages/0/d220355082/htdocs/bitme/core/composer/bin/phantomjs()
>   [0x41f5c4] 10  0x415b86
>   /kunden/homepages/0/d220355082/htdocs/bitme/core/composer/bin/phantomjs()
>   [0x415b86] 11  0x2b1fc0917b45
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)
>   [0x2b1fc0917b45] 12  0x4176a1
>   /kunden/homepages/0/d220355082/htdocs/bitme/core/composer/bin/phantomjs()
>   [0x4176a1] PhantomJS has crashed. Please read the bug reporting guide
>   at        http://phantomjs.org/bug-reporting.html and file a bug report.
>         Segmentation fault " int(0) NULL

Edit:

If I replace the phantomJS with latest download,

I get libicui18n.so.55 missing dependency

how can I install this with Composer?

Please note that this needs to be installed on a shared hosting machine, hence I do not have root/sudo access on the machine

All help is appreciated.

Comment: The url you are requesting does not return a 200 but a 302. You can check this using chrome inspector and the network tab. Everything works fine if you test the 302 status.

Comment: Actually it returns int(0)

Comment: `$request = $client->getMessageFactory()->createRequest('http://luclaverdure.com', 'GET');
$response = $client->getMessageFactory()->createResponse();
$client->send($request, $response);
var_dump($request->getStatus()); // 302
if($response->getStatus() === 302) {
    var_dump($response->getContent());
    die;
}`
Returns your homepage html's.
Are you sure you don't have a host setting setup to a different IP or something like that?

Comment: if you look at the response code above: ["status"]=>
      NULL

Comment: Tried another other urls, I still get 0 as status

Comment: Updated entry, please have a look @user1453870

Comment: Things are getting a little bit complicated if this is a shared hosting as you could find yourself pitted against permissions errors and such, you could try something like that:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35840359/libicuuc-so-55-cannot-open-shared-object-file
Which is to download the binary and manually install it, though on a shared hosting it may not work. Unfortunately, if this doesn't work I think you'll have to contact the hosting company and exchange with them on the issue because your code is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Check if your system runs SELinux (you can check that with `sestatus`) —- it can (and it will) try to harm PhantomJS, and it looks just like that.

Check out "**SELinux**" section on [phantomjs.org/troubleshooting](http://phantomjs.org/troubleshooting) for official solution.

Comment: @LucLaverdure if sestatus is unavailable, check if you have getenforce. If not, check if you have enough memory (both RAM and disk), PhantomJS could use some

Comment: memory and disk space takes almost no resources... More than 80% available

Comment: @LucLaverdure could you try to download version 2.0, not 2.1? Maybe that can help

Comment: @LucLaverdure if 2.0 doesn't work, try 1.9 -- it uses different engine

Comment: I did, still makes a segmentation fault